# Reading path files without using extra backslash

Tags: java, path, filepath, ini, ini4j

I have a .ini file that looks like this and am using ini4j to parse the file:

```
[Filepath]
Inbound=C:\Users\Bilbo\Desktop\Testing
```

I want to return that exact string (C:\Users\Bilbo\Desktop\Testing) and I have the following java code:

```
public static String ParseIniInbound (File iniFile) throws 
InvalidFileFormatException, IOException {
    String iniFileName = iniFile.toString();
    Ini ini = new Ini(new File(iniFileName));
    String InboundPath= ini.get("Filepath", "Inbound");
    return InboundPath;
}
```

However, what is returned is C:UsersBilboDesktopTesting

I tried putting quotes around the filepath in the .ini file to read it as a string but that didn't work. I used double slashes (C:\\Users\\Bilbo\\Desktop\\Testing) in the .ini file which returns what im looking for (C:\Users\Bilbo\Desktop\Testing) but I want to be able to just copy and paste a filepath and not have to manually put in double slashes in the .ini flie. Is there a way to read in a string from an .ini file with ini4j or another way around this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to disable escaping.

```
import org.ini4j.Config;
...
Config.getGlobal().setEscape(false);
```

Other alternative would be to use the Wini class instead

```
import org.ini4j.Wini;
...
Wini ini = new Wini(new File(iniFileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change slash for double slash after reading the file path:

```
public static String ParseIniInbound (File iniFile) throws 
InvalidFileFormatException, IOException {
    String iniFileName = iniFile.toString().replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
    Ini ini = new Ini(new File(iniFileName));
    String InboundPath= ini.get("Filepath", "Inbound");
    return InboundPath;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to just read the .ini file as a string? Because sometimes i'll be reading a file path from a server which uses multiple dashes like \\\\SERVER.COM\\EXAMPLE$\\ and so I could see potential problems when I have multiple slashes